# How to add data in a nested map?

Tags: go

I have a nested map data that
One of them is a list, and I want to add data to the list using the append method
but it return an error :

###### invalid argument: baseData["a"].(map[string]interface{})["actions"] (map index expression of type interface{}) is not a slice

```
baseData := map[string]interface{}{}

dateData := map[string]interface{}{
        "date": map[string]interface{}{
            "updatedAt": "yyyy-mm-dd",
            "isChanged": true,
        },
        "actions": []interface{}{},
    }
baseData["a"] = dateData

.....example
{
"a": {
    "actions": [],
    "date": {
        "isChanged": true,
        "updatedAt": "yyyy-mm-dd"
    }
},
"b": {
    "actions": [],
    "date": {
        "isChanged": true,
        "updatedAt": "yyyy-mm-dd"
    }
}
```

}

My codes

```
actionData := map[string]interface{}{
        "id":        data.Id,
        "action":    data.Action,
    }
    baseData["a"].(map[string]interface{})["actions"] = append(baseData["a"].(map[string]interface{})["actions"], actionData)
```

Comment: "but it return an error" --- it would be much more helpful if you provided the exact error message.

Comment: Thank you.
The error message is ： invalid argument: baseData["a"].(map[string]interface{})["actions"] (map index expression of type interface{}) is not a slice

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    dateData := map[string]interface{}{
        "actions": []interface{}{},
    }

    dateData["actions"] = append(dateData["actions"].([]interface{}), "foobar")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", dateData)
}
```

Output:

```
map[actions:[foobar]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
baseData := map[string]interface{}{}
dateData := map[string]interface{}{
    "date": map[string]interface{}{
        "updatedAt": "yyyy-mm-dd",
        "isChanged": true,
    },
    "actions": []interface{}{},
}
baseData["a"] = dateData

actionData := map[string]interface{}{
    "id":     data.Id,
    "action": data.Action,
}
baseData["a"].(map[string]interface{})["actions"] = append(baseData["a"].(map[string]interface{})["actions"].([]interface{}), actionData)
```